# Entity Framework not comparing byte arrays

Tags: c#, entity-framework, hash, entity-framework-6

I am inserting data, using EF, which contains a SHA512 Hash. I am then looking up the same data like this, but no results are returned:

```
var searchHash = requestToFind.GetSelfSha512Hash();
var foundRequest = _complianceContext.ScoreResults
    .Where(sr => sr.SearchHash == searchHash);
```

Both `sr.SearchHash` and `searchHash` are `byte[]`.

If I take out the `Where` clause, I do get 1 result. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: Try this:  Convert.ToBase64String(sr.SearchHash) == Convert.ToBase64String(searchHash)

Comment: What is the SQL type of SearchHash? Can you use SQL Profiler to determine what SQL Statement is being executed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equality operator does not work like you expect for byte arrays.  Try [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var foundRequest = _complianceContext.ScoreResults
  .Where(sr => sr.SequenceEqual(searchHash));
```

Comment: Based on the documentation, it is one pass through each byte array comparing corresponding bytes.  I doubt that will have much impact.  The only way to know for sure which approach is optimal is to profile.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made EF 7 build queries that compare byte[] values:

1. Declared an empty method that accepts two byte arrays and returns bool in my context Class:

```
public partial class DbContext 
{
    public static bool LessThanOrEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

2. In DbContetx.OnConfiguring() method defined a translation from this function to an SQL tree section:

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(
    typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(LessThanOrEqual), new[] { typeof(byte[]), typeof(byte[]) }))
    .HasTranslation(
    args =>
        new SqlBinaryExpression(
            ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual,
            args[0],
            args[1],
            args[0].Type,
            args[0].TypeMapping)
    );
```

3. Used this method in my Linq query:

```
    byte[] arr = ...
    db.tbl.Where(r => DbContext.LessThanOrEqual(r.arr1, arr) &&
                      DbContext.LessThanOrEqual(arr, r.arr2))
```

4. This Linq query produces the following SQL query:

```
    SELECT ...
    FROM tbl
    WHERE (b.arr1 <= @__arr_0) AND (@__arr_0 <= b.arr2)
```